# Нужно передать String из SearchViewAdapter'a в активность

Tags: java, android, android-search-view

Имеется адаптер, в котором на основе запроса формируется строка textToSpeech, мне нужно эту строку передать в активность. Код адаптера:

```
public class ProblemNameFilter extends Filter {

    private final String SEARCH_DATA = "SEARCH_DATA";


    ProblemNameAdapter adapter;
    List<GetProblemListResponse.Problems> filterList;
    Context context;
    public String textToSpeech;

    public ProblemNameFilter(List<GetProblemListResponse.Problems> filterList, ProblemNameAdapter adapter, Context context)
    {
        this.adapter=adapter;
        this.filterList=filterList;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if(constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0)
        {
            constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
            List<GetProblemListResponse.Problems> filteredProblems = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i=0; i < filterList.size(); i++)
            {
                if (context.getSharedPreferences(SEARCH_DATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("search", "code").equals("code")) {
                    if (filterList.get(i).getProblemCode().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {

                        filteredProblems.add(filterList.get(i));

                    }
                }else {
                    if (filterList.get(i).getProblemName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)) {

                        filteredProblems.add(filterList.get(i));


                    }
                }
            }

            results.count = filteredProblems.size();
            results.values = filteredProblems;
        }else {
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;

        }
        return results;
    }



    @Override
    public void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        adapter.problems = (List<GetProblemListResponse.Problems>) results.values;
        if (adapter.problems.size() == 1) {
            if (context.getSharedPreferences(SEARCH_DATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("search", "code").equals("code")) {
                textToSpeech = adapter.problems.get(0).getProblemName();


            } else if (context.getSharedPreferences(SEARCH_DATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("search", "").equals("text")) {

                textToSpeech = adapter.problems.get(0).getProblemCode();


            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для связи с активностью используйте интерфэйс.

В адаптере:

```
private SendText sendText;

public interface SendText{
    public void getText(String yourText);
}

public ProblemNameFilter(List<GetProblemListResponse.Problems> filterList, 
     ProblemNameAdapter adapter, Context context) {
    sendText = (SendText) context;
    ...
}
```

И, где нужно:

```
sendText.getText(yourText);
```

В активности:

```
MyActivity... implements ProblemNameFilter.SendText

@Override
public void getText(String text){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Заработало, а можно через вызов этого метода присвоить текстовой переменной в активности значение?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Через интерфэйс можно передавать практически любую информацию любых объемов, а при обработке (`@Override`) выполнять любой код, доступный для активности. Если вы хотите просто присвоить значение глобальной переменной, то да, можно.

Comment: У меня есть метод, который не может принимать глобальные переменные, поэтому я хочу получить строку через метод getText()

Comment: Сложно без кода сказать, что вы хотите сделать и почему ваш метод не может принимать глобальные переменные. Если интересно, можете задать новый вопрос и приложить к нему код

Answer (score 1):

Во всех примерах которые обычно приводят Filter делают как inner class к Adapter и он таким образом выставляет переменную, в вашем случае textToSpeech. В вашем случае ИМХО вам надо в добавить в publishResults перед         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
вызов запуска диктовки (с проверкой что старый старт еще не закончился). Т.е. у вас должно быть что-то
Activity - стартует процесс диктовки

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

Далее в Activity вы получите разрешение и инициализируете mTs внутри активити:

```
private TextToSpeech mTts;
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Далее в адаптере вы инициализируете filter и в коде filter вместо context лучше протащить mts. Вот эту конструкцию лучше также протащить в инициализации ontext.getSharedPreferences(SEARCH_DATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("search", "code") (она же не бдует меняться пока работает адаптер)?

Соответственно делаете так

```
 @Override
public void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

    adapter.problems = (List<GetProblemListResponse.Problems>) results.values;
    if (adapter.problems.size() == 1) {
        if (search_string.equals("code")) {
            textToSpeech = adapter.problems.get(0).getProblemName();


        } else if (search_string.equals("text")) {

            textToSpeech = adapter.problems.get(0).getProblemCode();


        }
    }
    mTts.speak(textToSpeech , TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: У меня фильтр и так является inner классом к адаптеру, textToSpeech у меня запускается внутри onCreate, мне нужно просто передать эту строчку, чтобы дополнить текст, который диктует TTS

Comment: Вариантов много - вы и так проносите контекст в адаптер, соответственно если пронесете еще mTs в момент его инициализации хуже уже и так не будет.  Если говорить про clean architecture - то в идеале textToSpeach - это LiveData которую вы обновляете из адаптера (фильтра), однако само проигрывание идет в event subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

Обычная передача экстра-данных через Intent

```
Intent intent = ....;
intent.putExtra("textToSpeech", textToSpeech);
startActivity(intent);
```

В принимающей активности:

```
String textToSpeech = getIntent().getString("textToSpeech", null);
```

Comment: Мне нужно получать эти данные в той же активности, где находится эта вьюха, поэтому интент здесь не подходит

Comment: Хоть пишите тогда описание подробнее